# JsonPath from a Field name

Tags: java, json, parsing, error-handling

I am working on an orchestration service. The service basically is a platform to call multiple downstream services and pass the error returned by them. The problem is that the error field returned by downstream service is according to the json schema of that service. 
e.g. -

```
    "details": [
            {
                "field": "downstream_service.request.path.field_name"
            }
        ]
```

My component however needs to return error in something like

```
"details": [
            {
                "field": "my_component/users/index/field_name"
            }
        ]
```

I have java POJO object for the `my_component` and i need to get the json path for the field with name `field_name`.

How to get the json path of a field from a POJO or Json object? I am looking for existing libraries or frameworks.

USER POJO

```
public class User extends HATEOASEntity implements ResourceModel {

 /**
 * Credentials allowed by the user.
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("credentials")
@Valid
private List<Credential> credentials = new ArrayList<Credential>();
/**
 * The business information collected from the customer to create a business
 * user.
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("business_details")
@Valid
private BusinessDetails businessDetails; 
}
```

BUSINESS DETAILS POJO

```
public class BusinessDetails {

/**
 * contact details entered by user.
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("phone_contacts")
@Valid
private List<Phone> phoneContacts = new ArrayList<Phone>();
/**
 * addresses entered by user
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("addresses")
@Valid
private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<Address>();
}
```

ADDRESS POJO

```
public class Address {

/**
 * Reference Identifier
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("id")
private String id;
/**
 * type of the address
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("type")
private Address.Type type;
/**
 * line-1 of the address
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("line1")
private String line1;
/**
 * line-2 of the address
 * 
 */
@JsonProperty("line2")
private String line2;
}
```

My downstream service will tell me that the error is in `Line_1`. Have mapped `Line_1` to `line1` of my schema definition. How can i return `user/business_details/addresses/line1` ?

Comment: Is "request" and "path" constructs in your POJO?  Can you post the POJO here?

Comment: A google search returns so many options. See this - https://code.google.com/p/json-path/

Comment: @ramp most of the results are for front mapping. None offer the json path finding of a field. The link you shared does not have any documentation on the usage for java. If you find it could you please share it. Thanks for the help.